# Style conflicting with spark component - FLEX

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, flex-spark

I had imported a project and while trying to build it, it gives me the following error -

> Declaration of style 'textShadowColor' conflicts with previous declaration in C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\frameworks\libs\spark.swc(spark.components:Button)

I tried to fix it using the information provided [here](http://www.ammap.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1972) but it did not fix the error.

I am using flash builder 4.6 and flex sdk 4.6

Could someone help me out with how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to search in the source code of migrated project for CSS style declaration "textShadowColor" and alter its name or returned value type.

Comment: Well.. thats the first thing I did.. But I could not find that style specified anywhere.. I am not sure where else it would have been defined.. I am using another library called "amcharts" and that is the one creating the problem. I guess in the swc file somewhere it is defined .. but how do I modify it?

Comment: Well, the developers of AmCharts said that they had changed the style declaration of "textShadowColor" in 1.0.2.0 release.

If this is not true, I would suggest to contact them via forum.

Comment: yeah.. I saw that post as well.. So what I did was replace the swc file with the latest one.. but still I was getting the same issue...

Comment: the latest amcharts is the amChartsFB4.swc file.. I replaced the amCharts.swc with the latest one but still I get the same error..

Comment: I downloaded 1.8.3.2 AmCharts http://flex.amcharts.com/download and tried "the Simple Pie Sample" together with Flex 4.6 SDK

No error was received concerning already declared style declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this problem also. But i got that solved
Download the latest amChart swc from [here](http://www.amcharts.com/wp-content/downloads/amcharts_flex_components_1.8.3.4.zip) and replace it with your previous one. You will have to change your code a little , specially you will need to delete "direction" property (if used) in your amchart legends. give it a try